# AttributeError: module 'tensorboard' has no attribute 'lazy'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard, attributeerror

I have a generative adversarial network using Keras with a tensorflow backend. I am running Tensorflow 1.14.0, Python 3.7.4, and Keras 2.2.4. The full error is:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Riley/PycharmProjects/shoeGAN/shoeWGAN.py", line 7, in <module>
    from keras.layers import *
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import compat
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v1\compat\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1.compat import v2
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v1\compat\v2\__init__.py", line 303, in <module>
    from tensorboard.summary._tf import summary
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorboard.summary import v2
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\summary\v2.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio.summary_v2 import audio
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\audio\summary_v2.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorboard.compat import tf2 as tf
  File "C:\Users\Riley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\compat\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import tensorboard.lazy as _lazy
AttributeError: module 'tensorboard' has no attribute 'lazy'
```

I didn't include the full code, because the error comes up during imports, which are below:

```python
import os

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.optimizers import *
from keras.initializers import *
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
from keras.preprocessing.image import save_img
```

Things I have tried:

- Restarting computer.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling all tensorflow and tensorboard libraries using pip and then restarting computer.
- The top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53966020/attributeerror-module-tensorboard-util-has-no-attribute-persistentopevaluato)

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1862) is the issue stating your error on Github.

At first, someone noted that only the nightly build of TensorBoard (`tb-nightly`) is compatible with the TF 2.0 preview, 1.12.2 is not expected to work.

One of the last comments suggests that the order of `tensorflow-tensorboard` and `tensorboard` matter, so you should fist

```
pip install tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1
```

and then

```
pip install tensorboard==1.14.0
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[tensorflow-tensorboard](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-tensorboard/) has been deprecated, so you should uninstall it and use the latest version of [tensorboard](https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard/) (2.4.0 at the moment of writing this reply).

```
pip install tensorboard
```

Comment: Uninstall ``tensorflow-tensorboard`` does the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard using following command.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard
```